# $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} v_i $ converges?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

If I have a series of vectors $(v_i)_{i\in V}$ in a vector space $V$. Then if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} v_i$, can I say that if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mid \mid v_i \mid \mid < \infty$ then the series converges? Or do I need the vector space to be complete, or some other conditions?

Comment: You need completeness.

Comment: Ah, I see. And why do I need completeness?

Comment: The condition you have can be used to show the sequence is Cauchy, and if the space is complete then the sequence converges but otherwise may fail to. As an example, take $V=\mathbb{Q}$ and $v_i = 1/i!$.

Comment: Oh, I see : $\| \sum_{i=1}^n v_i-\sum_{i=1}^m v_i\| \le \sum_{i=m+1}^n \| v_i \| < \epsilon$ for $n \ge m \ge N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the space of al sequences $ (a_n)$ of real numbers such that $a_n=0$ for $n$ sufficiently large with the norm defined by $\|(a_n)\|=\sum|a_n|$. Let $v_i$ be the sequence which has $\frac 1 {i^{2}}$ in the $i-$th position and $0$ elsewhere. Then $\sum\|v_i\| <\infty$ but $\sum v_i$ does not converge.  Can you verify this?

But the implication holds in any Banach space since the partial sums form a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: It doesn't converge since $(\frac{1}{i^2})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not in the space we consider because the terms don't become $0$ at some threshhold.

Comment: Yes. So $\sum v_i$ doesn't converge but $\sum \|v_i\|$ does.